# After Season 6, where does House Arryn's loyalty lie?

Tags: game-of-thrones

After Lyanna Mormont gave her speech and everyone started hooting-and-hollering, I'm not sure if anybody from the Vale (House Arryn) was voicing their agreement that Jon was the new King of the North.

Of course, the intentions of Lord Baelish are always unknown, but *officially*, is House Arryn:

1. declared as recognizing Jon as the new King of the North and ready to leave the easily defendable Vale and follow him into major combat?
2. declared as sympathetic to House Stark, but neutral? Going to war with any major army and risking major casualties will take convincing?
3. after Battle of the Bastards (BoB), the only remaining forces in the North are in the Vale? How many lesser Houses sat-out the BoB? It'd seem Jon has no army to command...

**At end of season 6, does House Arryn 100% follow the King of the North? Or are they sympathetic but neutral?**

Comment: to point 3) The vale isn't in the north is it? it's below the neck and in it's own right one of the seven kingdoms.

Comment: I don't think that the Vale is technically in the North, but the Vale and the North have a tiny bit of an adjacent border. That is how the Knights of the Vale rode into the North for BoB.

Comment: @khyle Not really a border. Vale is surrounded by Mountains of Moon on South-Western Side. The Northern parts of Vale do have a clear route to Kingsroad which then leads to North but they are separated from Eyrie and rest of the Vale by Sea and mountains. The plausible route is taking the High road from Eyrie, Get out at Bloody gate, Follow it to Cross-roads inn, get on the Kingsroad, follow it straight to the Neck and enter the north

Answer (score 8, accepted):

whoops. Just re-watched s6 finale. Littlefinger and Sansa dialogue:

> **Baelish**: News of this battle will quickly spread through-out the 7 kingdoms. I've declared for House Stark for all to hear.
>   **Sansa**: You've declared for other Houses before, and that has never stopped you from serving yourself.
>   **Baelish**: The past is gone for good. We can sit here mourning its departure, or prepare for the future. You, my love, are the future of House Stark.

So, Baelish has declared the Vale for House Stark (but technically only if Sansa, and not a bastard, is the leader of House Stark).

Comment: And Littlefinger looks surprised and displeased that Jon is getting the support of the North. You can almost see the gears in his mind spinning... "recalculating... recalculating...".

Comment: @AndresF. Baelish is definitely angling for a marriage to someone...